# Discord.js V14 create channel through reaction collector?

Tags: discord.js

I can't seem to make it work so when the emoji from the reaction collector gets clicked, a new channel gets created.

```
const { EmbedBuilder, ChannelType, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'channel',
  description: "Create own channel.",
  cooldown: 3000,
  userPerms: [],
  botPerms: [],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const msg = await message.reply('Building embed...');
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setTitle('Click on collector!')
      .setDescription(`Click on the  emoji to create your own channel.`);

    await msg.edit({ content: '\u200B', embeds: [embed] });

    await msg.react('');
    const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && !user.bot;
    const collector = msg.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 60000 });

    collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
      try {
        await reaction.users.remove(user.id);
        reaction.guild.channels.create({
            name: interaction.user.tag,
            type: ChannelType.GuildText,
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
              },
              {
                id: interaction.user.id,
                allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
              },
              {
                id: client.user.id,
                allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
              },
            ],
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });

    collector.on('end', async () => {
      await msg.reactions.removeAll();
    });
  }
};
```

I get error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')
at ReactionCollector. (/home/container/commands/info/t5.js:25:18)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

I tried all I could think of and solutions from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have made a typo that i saw instantly. As i have made that mistake as well.

`interaction.guilds.channel.create` > `interaction.guild.channels.create` you placed the `s` in the wrong spot :D

oh and another thing, you don't need to have `interaction.guild.roles.everyone` as `interaction.guild.id` is automatically everyone role.